# how to type keys in VM window?

Tags: pywinauto

I need to automate VMware and I am using pywinauto in python. I have automated till it shoes the VM window. Its detects the VM window( I know this because the mouse moves to the VM window and clicks on it). The problem is when I try to type keys it comes out of the window(focus is lost). So nothing gets typed in it. After this the code exits without showing any error.
My code is given below:

```
app.window(best_match='10.53.32.36-vSphereClient', top_level_only=True).child_window(best_match='Launch Virtual Machine ConsoleButton').click()
time.sleep(3)
app.window(best_match='bmvm03onlocalhost.localdomain', top_level_only=True).child_window(best_match='VMWindow').click_input()
time.sleep(3)
app.window(best_match='bmvm03onlocalhost.localdomain', top_level_only=True).child_window(best_match='VMWindow').type_keys("{ENTER}")
app.window(best_match='bmvm03onlocalhost.localdomain', top_level_only=True).child_window(best_match='VMWindow').type_keys("root"+"{ENTER}")
time.sleep(2)
```

Kindly help me with the error.

Comment: All virtual machines don't provide GUI elements info to local machine. The same is true for Remote Desktop or VNC. You have to copy your automation script to remote/virtual machine and run it inside.

Comment: ok. thank you for the clarification. Will try it.

Comment: Draft document about all this stuff: [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto-fork.readthedocs.io/en/dont_use_deprecated_methods/remote_execution.html)